# Is it possible to enable Google Bookmarks Sync in Chromium?

Tags: sync, google-chrome, chromium, bookmarks

I'm considering changing from Google Chrome to Chromium in order to get as open sourced as possible. However, I've always liked Google Chrome's ability to synchronize my bookmarks to my Google Account (I dual-boot with Windows).

Is there any way to enable Google Bookmarks Sync on Chromium, or is that a Chrome-only feature? I've looked around, but haven't been able to find any answers.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can,Chromium has the sync option, just enter your email and password.It will sync everything From Google Chrome. I am using Chromium this way.

Go to preferences - personal stuff :

[image]

Comment: Anytime, glad to help :)

Comment: As of Spring 2021 this functionality has unfortunately been disabled in Chromium.

Answer (score 1):

They are no longer building the Sync-APIs into Chromium, so it does not appear to be working with the current version 59.0.3062.0.  You would have to make your own build with those APIs included, or find an older version with them built-in.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, not anymore. Google [disabled this functionality](https://blog.chromium.org/2021/01/limiting-private-api-availability-in.html) on 15 March 2021.